# Scale Fixed Position Div With Window Resize (Angular)

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, mobile

Is there a way using Angular to scale the size of a div that has a fixed position to change size with a window size change? I want to have a div be fixed at a position on the page but resize for different browser sizes (mobile, dif screens, etc).

Comment: You can use an ng-class and implement that definition in css. You can use media queries to adjust the div size for different browsers.

Comment: Use percentage based widths in css.